# Stored procedure null column shows its type as Int in an Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this `SELECT` query in a stored procedure and in Entity Framework it shows property type `int`. How can I make the property type `string`? Here is the stored procedure:

```
alter procedure EquipmentRequest
as 
SELECT 
e.EquipmentName,  e.Id,
  null as Remarks
FROM
PECEquipment as e
```

I want the `null as Remarks` column value to be shown as string in EF. Right now its as:

```
public Nullable<int> Remarks { get; set; }
```

But it must be like this:

```
public string Remarks { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CAST` to get desired datatype(length):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE EquipmentRequest
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT e.EquipmentName,
         e.Id,
         CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Remarks   
  FROM PECEquipment as e;
END
```

`NULL` by default has `INT` datatype:

```
-- checking metadata
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
     N'SELECT NULL AS Remarks', NULL, 0)  
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
     N'SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS RemarksCasted', NULL, 0)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/449762)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║     name      ║ system_type_name ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Remarks       ║ int              ║
║ RemarksCasted ║ varchar(100)     ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Okay let me try :)

Comment: @user3515453 Make a complex type of this Procedure.. and add a parameter &  change its type to String .

Comment: Yes Its string Now.. Thanks Love 

Comment: Hehehe, I've just got `sql-server` gold badge :)

Comment: ☀✨ That is great for us and indeed for you too 